# How to Perform MFTF test to Custom Module before submit to Marketplace in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.4, mftf

I have go through the [MFTF documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/mftf/docs/introduction.html) to create and test the custom module before submitting the extension to Magento Marketplace. But this is difficult to understand to work on it.

Can some one share the simple example?

Thanks,